# Transit visa for Frankfurt, when traveling on separate tickets

Tags: schengen, transit, south-african-citizens, fra

I am a South African national based in Kuwait. I will be travelling to Dublin via Frankfurt. I will have two tickets issued online: one on Kuwait Airways KWI-FRA-KWI and another ticket on Aer Lingus, FRA-DUB-FRA.

Do I have to apply for a transit visa as I have two different tickets? I will be only carrying one hand bag no check in luggage .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both airlines let you check in online and print your boarding pass, you shouldn't need to exit the international area, so theoretically you wouldn't need a visa. However, there is a possibility that the airline will not let you board the flight in the first place, since as far as they know you are staying in Germany, so you probbly should contact them.

By the way, transit visas don't apply to you anyway, since your citizenship does not require one. If you end up needing a visa, it will be a full Schengen visa.